# What is the difference between webm and webm_chunk?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

*I am asking because I cannot check this myself, when running ffmpeg with "webm_chunk" format I get either "Output file #0 does not contain any stream" or "Could not write header for output file #0" error, just like in the question: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18032/dash-live-streaming*

Documentation for ffmpeg states that format "webm_chunk" creates webm chunked into separate files. However I can do this manually, running ffmpeg with "webm" format and adding option for chunk length -- ffmpeg will also create separate files, playabable, with given duration.

So what is the difference between "webm" (plus additional `chunk_*` options added) and "webm_chunk"?